# Why is $\limsup s_n \le \lim s_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My professor said that the ratio test for convergence that we use in analysis is stronger than the one we used in calculus, because the one in analysis uses lim sup, while the one in calculus uses just lim; this is what makes me conclude the inequality in the title. However, I can't picture any sequence for which lim sup is any different than just lim. If anything, it seems like lim sup should be $\ge$ just lim, not the other way around.

Comment: It cannot be possible that $\limsup s_n<\lim s_n$ but certainly the statement $\limsup s_n\le \lim s_n$ is true. In the same way is true that $\lim s_n\le \limsup s_n$. Anyway these expresions only makse sense if $\lim s_n$ exists. The statement is a kind of troll statement (I saw some of these troll statements in some books).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limsup criterion is stronger because the limsup always exists, but the limit may not.

Comment: Ah so when they both exist, it is never the case then that $\lim \sup s_n \not = \lim s_n$?

Comment: @Ovi That's right, if limit exists then lim sup = lim inf = lim.